# Confusion about MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to understand the difference between MOSFET and BJT's.
In particular I am considering the following switch circuit:

[image]

My understanding is as following : The \$V_{\text{Th}} = 2.2V\$ for the MOSFET. Since we apply a voltage of 3V we have \$V_{GS} > V_{\text{Th}}\$. However current in the drain is (at most) 5mA (since we can't pull the voltage of drain source below ground), so this means that \$V_{DS}\$ cannot be greater than \$V_{GS} - V_{\text{Th}}\$ as otherwise the drain current would have to be larger than 5mA (something proportional to \$C (V_{\text{GS}} - V_{\text{Th}})^2\$ with a large \$C\$).  So this means that \$V_{DS}\$ is small, and looking at the precise equation we can figure out \$V_{DS}\$ from
[image]
with \$I_{D} = 5\text{mA}\$.

Is my reasoning correct? If it is then I understand that in this regime of operation the MOSFET is quite similar to the BJT with the main difference that the base doesn't source current and moreover that the drain and the source can swap roles (if drain is more negative than the source for instance).

Comment: OMG, your equation is scary. I am a friendly hobbyist and I don't know nothing about what the symbols μ and λ etc stand for. But I do have some messing around experience with signal MOSFET (eg 2N7000) and power MOSFET (IRF540, IRL540 etc) . You seem to worry that for 2N7000, the current is limited to the order of 5mA. But if you wish to have big current, you can always use power MOSFET to switch current in the order of 1A, 10A, or even more. / to continue, ...

Comment: One big difference between switching BJT and power MOSFET is that the later's "on resistance" is much much smaller, therefore can handle big currents. If you can let us know the order of current to switch, I can give more appropriate comments. Cheers.

Comment: @nanofarad : I believe you are mistaken, the equation that I have given is the one that Wikipedia indicates for the triode mode, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Modes_of_operation

Comment: possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410955/triode-and-saturation-region-in-mosfet . @blaber see answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410955/triode-and-saturation-region-in-mosfet#410957

Comment: @blaber You're right, I didn't read it clearly. Dupes by VVT should be valid.

Comment: The datasheet for a 2N7000 Mosfet says its threshold Vgs is 3V max. Then some of them with a Vgs of 3V like you have conduct only 1mA. A low on-resistance for all of them is shown when Vgs is 4.5V and 10V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the FET in this case as a variable resistor; the resistance decreases (approximately) as 1/(VGS-VTH). Most FETs are much less than 5 kΩ, so when yo exceed the threshold, the drain voltage will quickly fall to (typically) 10's of mV.

Discrete FETs always have the drain-source diode internally in (anti-)parallel, so (unless you are operating at << 0.7 V) they really can't swap roles. Even if you could, generally the source-gate breakdown voltage is much less than the drain-source breakdown voltage.

Yes, it is similar to a bipolar device in saturation. A bipolar will work in saturation. In reverse it will also work, but not as well (reverse beta is quite low), and the maximum reverse voltage is about 6 V because the emitter-base junction breaksdown beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Some FETs have special drain implants, to achieve high voltages. Thus a major asymmetry would exist. Doing some on_chip design, I encountered both symmetric and a-symmetric devices, models, and layouts; in my case, these were all horizontal surface layout; that is, there was no useful vertical behavior inside the implants. The heat is dissipated only at the surface or 1 or 2 microns down. Thus Safe Operating Area is very small.

Some power FETs have the substrate be the Drain connection, with the wafer eutectically_bonded to the copper tab (1cm by 2cm or so) that removes heat.
This (vertical) FET construction uses the **entire** wafer thickness for the dissipation of heat, and the Safe Operating Area is very large.