# How to properly bias transistors used in switched capacitor circuits?

Tags: mosfet, switches, switched-capacitor

I am trying to simulate a switched capacitor circuit to implement a resistor.

First, I tried to do it with switches (top) figure. Then I tried to use MOS transistors in place of the switches.

[image]

Here's a simulation of the voltage of the capacitor.

[image]

The circuit with switches (shown in green) shows the expected behavior. The circuit with the transistors isn't behaving as expected. I tried connecting the bulk to the source and changing the gate voltages, but nothing seemed to make it work.

Comment: The FET Ron has to be much lower than 1 Ohm , which is likely too small

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Usually, the on resistance is more than 100Ohm.

Comment: You need about 1% of the series R, so the effective R is divided by duty cycle

Comment: I still don't understand what I need to do to make it behave like the circuit with switches. I completely removed the series resistances and there was no change. Can you tell me what to do to make it work like the one with the switches. Once it works, I can then try to understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You're only driving the gates with 2V signals. What is the threshold voltage of your MOSFETs? To do this right, you really need "transmission gates" rather than single MOSFETs. A transmission gate is an NMOS and a PMOS in parallel, driven with complementary clocks. That way, they can pull high and low equally well when "on".

Comment: If I set the gate voltage too high, wouldn't that put the transistor in the triode region (since VDS < VGS - VTH) ?

Comment: What is Vgs in each state? It can't work unless you use TG's

Comment: [Triode region](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/410955/11683) is exactly what you want in this application. You're trying to use the MOSFETs as low-impedance switches.

Comment: argh, why is BJT saturation not the same thing as FET saturation?