# How do I find the point where MOSFET changes from triode region to saturation?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos

[image: Question]

I have made a rough plot starting from the cutoff region, where \$\small V_{DS}=V_{DD}\$ until the input voltage crosses the threshold, and then the output voltage begins to drop (approximately linearly) until the transition to the triode region. Now my question is: at what value of the gate-source voltage does this take place?

I know that at this point, \$\small V_{DS}=V_{GS}-V_{th}\$,
and as such at that point the drain-source voltage is exactly 1 V higher than the gate-source voltage.

I also know that \$\small V_{DS}=V_\text{DD}-I_\text{DS} \cdot R_D\$. Do I just keep on plugging in values for the drain-source current until I get my desired value (which I have already tried a couple of times), or is there a more systematic way to solve this?

Comment: [Related Q and A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/410955/triode-and-saturation-region-in-mosfet)

Comment: Doesn't help much with my question...

Comment: Do you know the equation for Ids current?  Substitute it into \$ V_{DS} = V_{DD} - I_{DS}  R_S\$ Next you need to substituting the expression for \$V_{DS}=V_{GS}-V_{th}\$  in to the first equation and solve it for \$V_{GS}\$

Comment: OMG, I am so stupid... Thanks a lot man!

Comment: One last doubt! I should use the SAT region equation for $I_D$ right?

Comment: Yes, you need to use SAT region equation.